# Combine StackNavigator with Mobx props

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, mobx, mobx-react

I am trying to use StackNavigator together with MobX. Here is where I get stuck.

**index.android.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import DemoStore from './src/stores/DemoStore';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import PoolListComponent from "./src/components/PoolListComponent";
import TestComponent from "./src/components/TestComponent";

export default class TestApp extends Component {
  render() {
    const Navigator = StackNavigator({
      Home:  {screen: TestComponent},
      Pools: {screen: PoolListComponent}
    });

    return (
      <Navigator store={DemoStore} />
    )
  }
}

AppRegistry.registerComponent('TestApp', () => TestApp);
```

**TestComponent.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {observer} from 'mobx-react';
import {Button, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';

@observer
export default class TestComponent extends Component {

  static navigationOptions = {
    title: 'Home',
  };

  render() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;
    console.log(this.props.store)
    return (
      <View>
        <Button
          title="Pool overview "
          onPress={() =>
            navigate('Pools')
            // Poolsconsole.log(this.props.TestApp)
          }
        />
      </View>
    );
  }

}
```

**Demostore**

```
import {observable } from 'mobx';

class DemoStore{

  @observable name = 'Demo demo';
  @observable pools = [];
}

const demoStore = new DemoStore();
export default demoStore;
```

The above code works. With this, I mean that the TestComponent appears on the screen when loading the application.

However, I have the following questions:

1. How does the `index.android.js` know that it has to load the `TestComponent`?
2. In `TestComponent's` render method, `console.log(this.props.store)`prints `undefined`. How do I properly inject the store so that it will be available for all components? So when you look in my example it should be available in `TestComponent` and `PoolListComponent`

For the records:
I am using

```
"mobx": "^3.3.1",
"mobx-react": "^4.3.3",
"react": "16.0.0-alpha.12",
"react-navigation": "^1.0.0-beta.15"
```

Answer (score 0):

`index.android.js` picks the first route in the route config to display. The first route has a screen composed of `TestComponent`.

For passing props to all screen components, use [screenProps](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigators/stack#Navigator-Props).

```
<Navigator screenProps={{ store: DemoStore }} />
```

The store can be accessed using this.props.screenProps.store within each component.